# How can I add omitable dynamic values to an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am adding dynamical values to my array from two tables (datatables.js) as in here:

```
var formArray = {
    "valueFromA0" : table1.row(0).data()[1],
    "valueFromA1" : table1.row(1).data()[1],
    "valueFromB0" : table2.row(0).data()[1],
    "valueFromB1" : table2.row(1).data()[1]
};
```

These tables are also dynamically created. So some of the values (or even all of them) can be empty. I want to omit 'undefined'/empty values during the creation array. For example, say valueFromA1, valueFromB0 and valueFromB1 are undefined so it means there should be only one value in the array like this:

"valueFromA0" : "5"

Comment: That's not an array but an object

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var formArray = {
    "valueFromA0" : "7",
    "valueFromA1" : undefined,
    "valueFromB0" : "5",
    "valueFromB1" : undefined
};

function removeEmptyEntries(obj)
{
    for(var prop in obj)
    {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !obj[prop])
            delete obj[prop];
    }
}


removeEmptyEntries(formArray);
console.log(formArray);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zp94ybdq/).

Comment: it gives error an error and terminates if there is an 'undefined' to be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it with the object literal.

```
var formArray = {}, tmp;
if ((tmp = table1.row(0).data()[1]) !== undefined) formArray.valueFromA0 = tmp;
if ((tmp = table1.row(1).data()[1]) !== undefined) formArray.valueFromA1 = tmp;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `Object.keys()` , `Array.prototype.filter()` , `Array.prototype.forEach()` ; create new object , set properties where value not `undefined` at `formArray` object to new object

```js
var formArray = {
    "valueFromA0" : 1,
    "valueFromA1" : 2,
    "valueFromB0" : undefined,
    "valueFromB1" : undefined
};
// new `Object`
var res = {};

Object.keys(formArray).filter(function(val) {
  // filter `formArray` object keys where value not `undefined`
  return formArray[val] !== undefined
}).forEach(function(val) {
  // set properties , values at `res`
  res[val] = formArray[val];
});
console.log(res)
```